# error incomplete element type struct

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble compiling my code. Every time I compile it I get:

```
  rec5.c: In function âmainâ:
  rec5.c:7:17: error: array type has incomplete element type
struct Item cart[3];
             ^
  rec5.c:8:16: error: array type has incomplete element type
struct Item book[4];
            ^
  rec5.c:9:16: error: array type has incomplete element type
struct Item clothing[5];
            ^
  rec5.c:10:16: error: array type has incomplete element type
struct Item sports[6];
            ^
  rec5.c:20:5: error: expected â;â before âprintfâ
printf("%s %d %d", book.name, book.price, book.quantity);
^
  rec5.c:24:6: error: expected â;â before âprintfâ
printf("%s %d %d", clothing.name, clothing.price, clothing.quantity);
^
  rec5.c:28:6: error: expected â;â before âprintfâ
printf("%s %d %d", sports.name, sports.price, sports.quantity);
```

I tried using typedef before struct but I got "array size not declared".  I can't tell why Item isn't being declared properly.  The function is supposed to ask the customer which item they want, and then display the proper data.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    struct Item cart[3];
    struct Item book[4];
    struct Item clothing[5];
    struct Item sports[6];

    book.name = "harry potter";
    book.price == "$100";
    clothing.name = "shirt";
    clothing.price == "$15";
    sports.name = "football";
    sports.price = "20";

    scanf("enter Item %c", cart.type);

    if (cart.type == "book"){
        scanf("please enter quantity %d", book.quantity)
        printf("%s %d %d", book.name, book.price, book.quantity);
    }
    if (cart.type == "clothing"){
        scanf("please enter quantity %d", clothing.quantity)
        printf("%s %d %d", clothing.name, clothing.price, clothing.quantity);
    }
    if (cart.type == "sports"){
        scanf("please enter quantity %d",sports.quantity)
        printf("%s %d %d", sports.name, sports.price, sports.quantity);
    }
}

struct Item
{
    char *type;
    char *name;
    double price;
    double quantity;
};
```

Comment: tip: you can use free tools like AStyle to fix the formatting of your code before posting

Answer (score 3):

Your `struct` is being used before being defined.  Simply move your `struct` definition to be above your `main()` function.